# Cant access my Json output from php

Tags: php, angularjs

I have PHP file (car_insert.php) that contain

```
$datasuccess = array(
    "name" => "Person Name",
    "email" => "Person email",
    "phone" => "phone"
);
echo json_encode($datasuccess);
```

My angularjs code is

```
$scope.insertCarInfo=function(){
    $http.post("car_insert.php",{
        'REMARKS':$scope.REMARKS,
        'buttonName':$scope.buttonName})
            .success(function(datasuccess){
                $scope.name = datasuccess.name;
                $scope.email= datasuccess.email;
                $scope.carDisplay();
            });
    };
```

My HTML(index.php) file is code is :

```
Name:{{name}}
email:{{email}}
```

I cant get any output

Comment: try json_encode($datasuccess, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: What exactly does *"can't access"* mean? Does success handler fire?

Comment: cant get any output in my index.php, when i trying to get output through 
'Name:{{name}}
email:{{email}}'
but i can see my echo jason as "{"name":"Person Name","email":"Person email","phone":"phone"}" in my car_index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.name = datasuccess.name;
$scope.email= datasuccess.email;
$scope.carDisplay();
$scope.$apply();//insert this code.
```